# Como remover um item já selecionado de um multiple upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, multiple

Tenho esse exemplo e gostaria de remover um item da minha seleção. Porém  não está removendo adequadamente, tem um problema com o número do index, como poderia resolver isso?

**https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/yrvyf2gn/**

Comment: Quando você usa a função `splice` está retornando `typeError`, provavelmente porque files não é um `array` e sim o `object` com `prototype` FileList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apos uma longa procura descobri que o `input` do tipo `file` possui um atributo `files` com herança protótipo de `File`, seus valores são **readonly**, neste caso não é permitido fazer qualquer alteração.

Existe uma forma de contornar isto, criando um array e jogando os arquivos selecionados dentro dele e trabalhando com a seleção a partir do mesmo.

Basicamente você usa o `input` apenas para pegar os arquivos, o tratamento é todo feito através do array, tanto exclusão como envio para o servidor. Qualquer dúvida sobre o código abaixo deixe no cometário. Também tem alguns detalhes, se quiser usar desta forma terá que esconder o texto defualt do `input` e criar o seu próprio.

> Veja funcionando aqui no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/1tjhw7tx/).

**Exemplo:**

```js
'use strict'

var APIFiles = {
  files: [],
  select: function(e) {
    if(this.files.length > 1) {
      for(var i = this.files.length; i > 0; i--) {
        this.files.splice(i, 1);
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].remove();
      }
    }

    var tempArray = [];
    [].forEach.call(e.target.files, function(file, index) {            
      tempArray.push(file);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var nodeImg = document.createElement('img');
        nodeImg.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        nodeImg.setAttribute('id', index);
        nodeImg.setAttribute('data', 'img');
        document.getElementById('listFiles').appendChild(nodeImg);
      }; 
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    this.files = tempArray;
  },
  send: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    this.files.forEach(function(file) {
      data.append('files', file);
    });
    // Send FormData with XMLHttpRequest
  },
  remove: function(e) {
    this.files.splice(e.target.id,1);
    document.getElementById('listFiles').removeChild(e.target);
  }
};

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  APIFiles.select(e);
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.id === 'send')
    APIFiles.send(e)
  else if(e.target.getAttribute('data') === 'img')
    APIFiles.remove(e);
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" multiple>
<p id="lenFiles"><p>
<div id="listFiles"></div>
<button id="send">Enviar</button>
```

**Edit: 22/08 - Remover itens após requisição.**

```
  {...}
  send: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    this.files.forEach(function(file) {
      data.append('files', file);
    });
    // Send FormData with XMLHttpRequest
    // Após fazer a requisição, se for bem sucedida chamar a função que remove os itens
    APIFiles.removeAll();
  },
  removeAll: function() {
    var listChilds = document.getElementById("listFiles");
    while (listChilds.firstChild) {
      listChilds.removeChild(listChilds.firstChild);
    };
  }
  {...}
```

Código da função removeAll foi retirado desta pergunta [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Referência: [Raymond Camden's Blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/04/14/MultiFile-Uploads-and-Multiple-Selects-Part-2)

Referência: [SOen - how to remove...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Referência: [MDN - FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/FileReader)

Referência: [MDN - File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Referência: [MDN - FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

Comment: Eu entendi o que você fez @devgaspa, só que eu tentei aplicar no meu exemplo e não deu muito certo... dá uma olhada lá. Obrigado.

Comment: Cara, eu consegui, usei seu exemplo, e adaptei, agora está funcionando:
https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/yrvyf2gn/

Comment: @IvanFerrer Excelente noticia, vi que tinha postado que não tinha conseguido mas estava meio corrido pra tentar ver, que bom que está funcionando. Agora vamos torcer para que mudem essa especificação de não poder alterar o objeto files né? rsrs. Estou pensando também em desenvolver uma directive para AngularJs, te envio o link do github caso queira contribuir. Abraço.

Comment: Não está removendo os arquivos selecionados após o submit, como resolver isso?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 tem que alterar o send para apos enviar, se o status do request for ok, remover os itens dai!

Comment: Sou leigo em javascript, como seria isso?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado de novo, mas me desculpa, onde eu coloco esse código? sou muito leigo em JS...

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 Entra no chat ai para eu poder te ajudar melhor. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44360/discussion-between-devgaspa-and-ngthm4r3

Comment: Agradeço,Já postei lá...

Comment: Alguma atualização?